# Add value in database to track the transaction before going over paypal site

Tags: razor, paypal, subscribe

I have used "Subscribe" Button in one of my application as below:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXX">
    <input name="custom" value="@MyUserID" type="hidden">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

`@MyUserID` is the identity value of my inserted entry to track the transaction and will update the same record when we come back to our site.

Now, I want to insert the transaction entry in the database to track it when we come back to our site. so at which place should I insert the database and how.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you populating the `custom` value? When you define your `@MyUserID` you can `INSERT` the value into your database at that time.

Why do you need it to be before the user is redirected to PayPal? That may turn out to be a problem if the user doesn't complete the payment. You should wait until after the transaction has occurred. Using IPN you'll get a post back to a notification script and you can grab the `custom` value and whatever else you need and toss it into a database.

Comment: I want to keep track of all the payments taken place, so when transaction just take place, I simply mark it as `pending` in case if user will not complete the transaction so when the control comes to an IPN page, how will I update the specific row in the database.?

Comment: You can check for the "custom" value in the IPN you've defined in the original redirect to PayPal. If that matches an entry in your DB you can update the "pending" status.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did..and it was working..I just want to clarify that...Thanks..